# SQL Extended Check Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, check-constraint

Is it possible to have a complex Check Constraint?

for example I have a customers table each record of which is assigned a customer type.

therefore I could have several customers with the same type.

I want to set one customer for each type to be the "Primary" account for that type, however only one customer for each type can be Primary.

Is it possible to add a check constraint on the IsPrimary field that checks all customers of the same type to see if there is already one marked as primary?

I can do this in C# code obviously but I would like this as an extra check.

I could also use a trigger but I would like to stick to constraints so that I can handle errors in the same way for all errors.

Thanks

Comment: `CHECK` constraints can only constrain either a single column (column check constraint) or all columns in a single row (table check constraint). Standard SQL also describes `ASSERTION`s, that can apply against all rows in a table, but I don't believe much research has gone into how `ASSERTION`s can be made to perform efficiently so most database systems still don't actually implement them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly a check constraint problem.  It is a filtered unique index problem.

```
create unique index customers_type_isprimary on customers(type)
    where isPrimary = 1;
```

This will guarantee that at most one customer has the `isPrimary` flag set for each type.

EDIT:

A filtered index is an interesting creation.  There are various resources explaining them (such as [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/introduction-to-sql-server-filtered-indexes/)), in addition to the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx).

The idea is to build an index only on rows that match the `where` clause in the index creation step.  One reason to do this is to reduce the size of the index.

Here is a use case with your data structure.  You might have a bunch of queries that filter on `isPrimary = 1`.  You never filter on `isPrimary = 0` -- you would just leave this out of the `where` clause.  Why clutter up the index with all the unnecessary values?  If the predicate is in the query, then the index can be used.

The case of the `unique` index is more compelling.  Filtered unique indexes do exactly what you are asking for -- ensuring that at most one value with `IsPrimary` is set for each type.  It does this by creating an index on `type` only for customers that have `IsPrimary` set.  The "unique" part of the index guarantees that each type only appears once in the index, and by extension, only one customer can have `IsPrimary` set for each `type`.

Comment: Forgive me for being an idiot but could you explain a bit further how this works please? This doesnt make sense to me from my understanding of Indexes.